# Display PDF File In Django Templates (FileField)

Tags: django, templates, model, filefield

**models.py**

```
class Summary(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    text = RichTextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%y/%m/%d', null=True)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf', null=True)
    pages = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def summary_pdf(request, pk):
     summary = Summary.objects.get(id=pk)

     if not request.user.is_authenticated:
         return redirect('login')

     context = {'summary': summary}
     return render(request, 'main/summary_pdf.html', context)
```

**summary_pdf.html**

```
<body>
   <embed src="{{ summary.pdf.url }}" width="800px" height="900" />
</body>
```

The problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIcbW.png)

Can someone help me?
I've been stuck in this since morning and haven't found a solution.

Comment: Please paste your code into your question rather than linking images, it makes it easier to answer your question

Comment: Try use a anchor tag, for example `<a href="{{ summary.pdf.url }}">Download</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an indentation error in your models.py

you should add 4 spaces before the line where you set the text attribute.

If this solution does not work, check your runserver terminal. Because if the problem is in PDF rendering and DEBUG is true in the settings.py file, Django should not show you the page whose photo you entered.

Comment: It's a typo that just happened when I wrote the question, I'll edit it right away.  
But it is written correctly in the main code